# AngularJS Update & PUT

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm trying to update data in an object on the view,  my service looks like this:

```
 .service('Tag', function Tag($resource, API) {
    return $resource(API.baseUrl + '/api/tags/:id', { id:'@_id' }, {

    update: {
      method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'}},

    delete: {
      method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}


  })

 });
```

my Controller

```
 angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('EditorTagsCtrl', function ($scope, Tag,$routeParams) {

$scope.tag = Tag.query()

$scope.updateTag = function()
{
 Tag.update()
  console.log ('working?')

}
```

});

Im getting a 404 error and the data is not passing to the back end.

Please help

Comment: You want to pass an `id` to resource update operation. Is your `$scope.updateTag` function not supposed to have an argument?

Comment: so like this?    $scope.updateTag = function(tag)
    {
     Tag.update(tag);
      console.log ('working?')

    }

Comment: i keep getting this error,angular.js:9435
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://stagingapi.myapp.com/api/tags. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.  but there is nothing wrong with the back end

Comment: What did you use for back end implementation? Seems like it has to do with CORS.